# Range(myRng).Copy throws "Range of object _global failed" when there's too much data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a raw data table that contains information of people. Every person is ranked in one of five categories (Quintiles):

Top 20%, Q4, Q3, Q2, Bottom 20%

My macro looks for each person in the Top 20%, selects it and then adds it to a range called `myRng`. Once everyone in the table with the Top 20% has been added to the range, it populates the Top 20% table.

The macro iterates for each one of the five categories.

The macro works with data samples that are (over ~80 Rows) but crashed and throws  `Range of object _global failed` If there's too much data.

If I click debug, the `Range(myrng).Copy` line 25 gets highlighted.

Here's the macro:

```
Sub populateTable(quintile As String, destinationTblName As String, sourceTblName As String)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("PRR Quintile Buckets").Activate
    Worksheets("PRR Quintile Buckets").Range("A1").Select

    Dim table As Range

'Clear table data
    Worksheets("PRR Quintile Buckets").Range(destinationTblName).Clear
    Worksheets("PRR Quintile Buckets").Range(destinationTblName).ClearContents
    Worksheets("PRR Quintile Buckets").Range(destinationTblName).Rows.Delete

'Fetch new data
    Worksheets("raw_data").Activate
    Set table = Sheets("raw_data").Range(sourceTblName)
    For Each cell In table.Columns(3).Cells
        If myRng = Empty And cell = quintile Then
            myRng = cell.Offset(, -1).Address(0, 0) & ":" & cell.Offset(, 5).Address(0, 0)
        ElseIf cell = quintile Then
            myRng = myRng & "," & cell.Offset(, -1).Address(0, 0) & ":" & cell.Offset(, 5).Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next cell

'Prepare data for table insertion and then copy
    Worksheets("raw_data").Range(myRng).Copy
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Worksheets("PRR Quintile Buckets").ListObjects.Item(destinationTblName)
    With Worksheets("macro_sandbox")
        .Activate
        .Range("a1").Select
        .Paste
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Style = "Normal"
        Range("C1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Style = "Percent"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Range("a1").Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

        For i = 0 To Selection.Rows.Count - 1
            tbl.ListRows.Add
        Next i

    End With
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("PRR Quintile Buckets"). _
        ListObjects(destinationTblName).Range.Cells(2, 1)
    Sheets("macro_sandbox").UsedRange.ClearContents
    Worksheets("macro_sandbox").Activate
    Worksheets("macro_sandbox").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I think it could be because the Range(rng1, rng2,...,rangN) has too many ranges in it.

Or maybe, because the Range(myRng).Copy method can't support that many selections.

Any idea what may be causing this issue? Is there a better way to populate tables?

Wish I could attach the workbook but it's confidential. If needed I could try building a mock-up workbook.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you first declare `myRng`? Add `Debug.Print myRng` right before the `.Copy` line.  What is the output in the Immediate Window? (Press CTRL+G in the VBEditor)

Comment: Line 17, inside the If statement is where I use it the first time. I don't declare it. I saw this once ans have been using it ever since. I should declare it though, to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: `Option Explicit` is your friend. Have you checked what the value is of `myRng` when you get to that line? might be worth a look

Comment: If you don't declare your variables, by default they are set as `variants`. This could potentially cause problems.. not convinced that's the issue here but it's always good practice to declare all your variables.. even if you want to declare them as `variants` or `objects`

Comment: I explicitly declared `myRng` as `String`. It's still crashing. I'm gonna try `Debug.print myRng` to check.

Comment: It's printing a string of ranges, looks like this: `B5:H5,B17:H17,B21:H21, ...`. Should I attach the workbook?

Comment: The `.Address` property of a `Range` is limited to 256 characters in length. I'd suggest using `Application.Union` instead.

Comment: Thanks @comintern! I ended up refactoring the macro. It now pastes each row in an auxiliary worksheets, then I get just range. I'm sure your approach would have been more clean but I tested it today with ~1000 rows and it ran in ~15 so I'm happy!

Thanks to all of you!